# v-combobox, strange behaviour

Tags: vuetify.js

I am having a weird problem with my v-combobox that is hard to explain but I will try my best.

When i start typing in the combobox the "list" gets filtered and if i click one of the items in the dropdown menu everything is fine.

The problem hapens if i click an item and then add another letter and directly press the send button in my form, the new charachters in my combo box is not passed to my axios request. If i instead change to another field all the information in my combobox is passed to the axios.post request.

But the weirdest part is that if i put:

```
console.log(this.shortname)
```

The output contains all characters in the combobox but not in the axios.post request.

Below is my code.

```
// TEMPLATE
<v-combobox v-model="shortname" color="forms" :items="shortnames" autocomplete="off"></v-combobox>


// SCRIPT
sendForm(){
   console.log(this.shortname)
   axios.post('/endpoint, {
                shortname: this.shortname
            })
            .then((response) => {})
}
```

So in the sendForm() function if i type "Richa" in the combobox and click the "Richard" listitem the

```
 console.log(this.shortname) // outputs "Richard" and so will axios request
```

But if i type "Richa" and click the "Richard" listitem and then ADD "sdf" (Richardsdf)
the

```
 console.log(this.shortname) // outputs "Richardsdf" but axios request is still "Richard"
```

However if i change fields after I add "sdf" axios.post will have "Richardsdf"

Im using vuetify version 2.4.2 and same behaviour on chrome and safari

My question is if there is a way to be able to get all added info into the combobox without having to change input fields?

// Best regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I added id="targetInput" and @update:search-input="updateTargetInput" and removed the v-model to combobox

```
 <v-combobox id="targetInput" @update:search-input="updateTargetInput" :items="shortnames" outlined :rules="shortnameRules"></v-combobox>
```

and in the methods i added

```
 methods: {
 updateTargetInput(currentValue){
        this.shortnameone = currentValue
        console.log(this.shortnameone)
    },
 }
```

Credits go to PradeepNooney
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4679#issuecomment-682456398